# I have no identification to get on the bus, how does that work?

Tags: tickets, buses, identity-cards, greyhound

I have no identification, but I do have a face sheet from a treatment center with my face and information on it. I also have my California foodstamp card with my name and my debit card with my name. How can I get on the Greyhound bus with no I.D.?

Comment: Can you get a California state id?

Comment: What ID (if any) does Greyhound require?

Comment: Greyhound doesn’t check ID. Bless them!

Comment: Greyhound does require I'd of you're picking up tickets for will call, though.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas apparently only if you pick them up from a person.  At a kiosk, the confirmation number is sufficient.

Comment: Never seen the kiosks, but I've also not rode Greyhound in a few years. :)

Answer (score 7):

I spoke with Greyhound Customer service on June 21, 2019.

A person without an official ID has one option, which is to pre-pay a ticket online.  It has an $18.00 fee on top of the ticket price and is only available in the United States, but it may be your only option.

She told me employees are not allowed to sell a ticket without an official ID, and the debit card won't be enough. The official identification card needs a picture, a first and last name, and an expiration date. It sounds like you may not have that, but, as someone suggested in a comment, a State ID card is a perfect alternative. I'm handicapped and can't have a driver's license, and I use my Massachusetts State ID card for everything!

To order the ticket online, choose the [Book a Trip](https://www.greyhound.com/en/) option at Greyhound's website. When you get to the point of purchase and enter the user information, you'll be asked to choose a password. The ticket will be created with a confirmation number. When you use the ticket you need both the password and the confirmation number. (This is designed as a way to buy a ticket for someone else, but it works fine even if it's for yourself.)

From [Pre-paid ticket orders](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/ticket-info/cardholder-not-traveling):

> To pick up their tickets at the station, the person traveling will need to provide:
>
> Photo ID or password chosen by the person purchasing the ticket
> Confirmation Number

There are some discounts available to help offset the ticket price. [This page](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/ticket-info/discounts) has a list.

Answer (score 5):

Did you already purchase your ticket online? Just go to the kiosk at the Greyhound station and enter the confirmation number. It will print out your ticket. Or log in to the Greyhound app on your phone. If you use the app, you need to check in with the app 2 hours before departure, and then just show the QR code to the driver. No ID required.

Don't have a ticket yet? Just go to the counter and buy one with your debit card.

Comment: and if i purchase at the stand they wont i.d me?

Comment: what is will call?

Comment: @jordanmweiss I've most often seen "will call" at theater and concert hall box offices. It refers to people who have bought tickets in advance that were not sent by mail. "Will call" refers to people who "will call" at the box office window to pick them up ("call" used to mean "visit" before the invention of the telephone, and since then has continued to be used in that sense in a diminishing number of contexts). So for bus tickets, it means that you'll pick them up at the station.  These days, that could be either from a window clerk or an automated kiosk.

Comment: @jordanmweiss I've never had to show ID when buying the ticket in person.

Comment: @jordanmweiss You can also buy your ticket online and show your tickets with an app on your phone. You won't be asked for ID; you just have to show the driver the QR code from the app. I did this last month.